# How can I create a standalone PEX (PEX that includes its dependencies) file with BUCK?

Tags: python, buck

Suppose I have the following project structure:

```
├── BUCK
├── main.py
└── setup.py
```

Where:

**main.py**

```py
from markdown import markdown

def joke():
    return markdown(u'Wenn ist das Nunst\u00fcck git und Slotermeyer?'
                    u'Ja! ... **Beiherhund** das Oder die Flipperwaldt '
                    u'gersput.')

print joke()
```

**setup.py**

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="packaging-hello-world",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="A hello world that attempts to package a Python project with its dependencies",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'markdown',
    ],
)
```

and

**BUCK**

```py
python_binary(
    name = 'bin_main',
    main_module = 'main',
    deps = [
        ':src_main',
    ],
    package_style = 'standalone',
    visibility = [
        'PUBLIC',
    ],
)

python_library(
    name = 'src_main',
    srcs = glob([
        '*.py',
    ]),
    visibility = [
        'PUBLIC',
    ],
)
```

***`markdown` is installed in the `virtualenvironment`.***

Using the standard `pex` tool, I can do: `pex . markdown -c main.py -o joke.pex` where the generated `joke.pex` contains the required dependencies (markdown). Example: `unzip joke.pex -d tmp ; tree -a -I .bootstrap -L 2 tmp` leads to:

```
tmp
├── .bootstrap
│   ├── _pex
│   └── pex
├── .deps
│   ├── Markdown-3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
│   ├── packaging_hello_world-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
│   └── setuptools-41.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
├── PEX-INFO
├── __main__.py
└── __main__.pyc
```

How can I make BUCK's generated PEX (`buck build :bin_main`) also contains `markdown`? I've tried to use `prebuilt_python_library` pointing to a wheel file generated from `setup.py` and add it as dep of `bin_main`, however, the generate PEX still doesn't contain the required deps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add it with the `prebuilt_python_library` but don't forget to add it as a `deps` inside the `python_library`.

```
remote_file(
    name='markdown-download',
    url='https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/4e/fd492e91abdc2d2fcb70ef453064d980688762079397f779758e055f6575/Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl',
    sha1='b80598369cacd1f28b9746dd5469f2573e545178',
    out='Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl',
)

prebuilt_python_library(
    name='markdown',
    binary_src=':markdown-download',
    visibility=['PUBLIC'],
)
```

The issue with this approach is that you have to specify all the deps by hand. Markdown is using `setuptools` so you need to download it with a `remote_file/prebuilt_python_library`.

I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked for me.